# Rect transform global Vector3 position

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Spawn : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject[] shopCells; // I just dragged from hierarchy RectTransform with childrens

    private void Start()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
        {
            print(shopCells[0].transform.GetChild(i).transform.position);
        }   // The results are the same for each iteration...
    }
}
```

I have grid layout group(parent) and want to instantiate prefabs on each children cell. Where to look ?

Tried some stuff but with no results. Ditch the rectTransforms and go with ordinary objects ?

Update *===============================

So i figure out that Grid layout and instantiating happening at the same time. I need Something like LateUpdate() but for Start().

Done with Coroutine but its temporary solution...

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Unity.VisualScripting;
using UnityEngine;

public class Spawn : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject[] spawn;
    public GameObject[] shopCells;

    private void Start()
    {
        StartCoroutine(Wait(2, SpawnPrefabs));
    }

    IEnumerator Wait(int time, Action func)
    {
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(time);
        func();
    }
    void SpawnPrefabs()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
        {
            var random = UnityEngine.Random.Range(0, spawn.Length - 1);
            var obj = Instantiate(spawn[random], shopCells[0].transform.GetChild(i).transform.position, Quaternion.identity);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You would probably have to use [`Canvas.ForceUpdateCanvases`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Canvas.ForceUpdateCanvases.html)

> Force all canvases to update their content.
>
> A canvas performs its layout and content generation calculations at the end of a frame, just before rendering, in order to ensure that it's based on all the latest changes that may have happened during that frame. **This means that in the Start callback and the first Update callback, the layout and content under the canvas may not be up-to-date**.
>
> Code that relies on up-to-date layout or content can call this method to ensure it before executing code that relies on it.

---

Though your approach is actually not that bad either. I understand and agree that this feels like a workaround - but Unity Canvas kind of requires these sometimes unfortunately. You can probably just stick to delay for one frame using

```
yield return null;
```

instead so your spawning is happening in the second frame

---

General coding style comment:

You should not use hard-coded magic values but use the actual existing ones like e.g.

```
void SpawnPrefabs()
{
    foreach (Transform child in shopCell[0].transform)
    {
        // Also note: For int the upper bound is exclusive
        // meaning this already will return values including 0 and spawn.Length - 1
        var random = UnityEngine.Random.Range(0, spawn.Length);
        var obj = Instantiate(spawn[random], child.position, Quaternion.identity);
    }
}
```

Comment: Wow, thank you. Definitely will try it out.